# Understanding a probability inequality from Billingsley's Converegence of Probability Measures

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, inequality, conditional-probability

In the below proof, I cannot figure out how we get the final inequality. Namely, how do we show that 
$$P[\tau_i^n - \tau_{i-1}^n \ge \delta' | \tau_q^n < m] \ge 1-\eta/P[\tau_q^n < m]$$ from (16.29)?

[image]